# Why does cloning an object to modify properties also modify the original object?

Tags: javascript, object, assign

I am very new to react and material-IU. This is the structure that is passed to each selector to configure it and that shows the three default options

```
export const questionOptions = {
  defaultValue: undefined,
  control: {
    type: "select",
    options: {      
      Accept: true,
      Decline: false,
      Unknown: undefined,
    },
  },
};
```

And this is how each component is configured for the title and its options

```
export const types = {
  startAdornment: {
  title: "First Text",
  ...questionOptions,
  },
  startAdornment: {
  title: "Second Text",
  ...questionOptions,
  },
}
```

I have to create a third select and I want to show only the first two options so I clone the object and modify the properties I want

```
export const questionOptionsTwo = Object.assign({}, questionOptions);

questionOptionsTwo.control.options = { Accept: true, Decline: false, }
```

And then use this new object for the third select

```
startAdornment: { 
   title: "Third Text", 
   ...questionOptionsTwo, 
},
```

the problem is that, although I am cloning the original object, when I modify the properties in the cloned object they are also modified in the original.

What am I doing wrong?
thank you all in advance

Comment: because this is not a clone, this is te same object with  different addressins names

Comment: you are doing what is called a shallow copy, objects are referenced in javascript.
please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `Object.assign` is only a shallow copy, so `questionOptionsTwo.control` still refers to the exact same object as `questionOptions.control`

Comment: deep copy vs shallow copy